# Create hyperlink in Excel file using AppleScript

Tags: excel, applescript, excel-2008

In Excel 2008 on Mac, I want to create a hyperlink on sheet 1 on cell "A8" using AppleScript in same Excel document.

`<hyperlink ref="A8" location="Sheet1!A20" display="Sheet1!A20" />`

I have tried the following script, which does not work:

```
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
   make new workbook
   tell worksheet "Sheet1" of active workbook
       make new hyperlink of cell "A8" with properties {address :"#Sheet1!A20", text to display:"Sheet1!A20"}
   end tell
end tell
```

Can you help me figure out what to do please?

Comment: What happens? In what way does your script fail? Your script is very incomplete. There should be a `Tell application ...` etc. Can you give the full script?

Comment: k, above see complete script for excel.

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Is there an active workbook?

Comment: My hyperlink is show in sheet 1 but not working.

Comment: Some extra text is add in hyperlink address i.e. %23Sheet1!A20 . If this text is deleted as manually then my hyperlink is to be work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a tough one! The following works:

```
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    tell worksheet "Sheet1" of active workbook
        make new hyperlink of cell "A8" with properties {address:"", sub address:"$A$20", text to display:"Sheet1!A20"}
    end tell
end tell
```

Note - I have edited this answer to improve it. In the first attempt at this, I did not have the `address:""` right. You pointed this out yourself in your comment. This is the missing piece - using `""` as `address` creates a reference to "this document". Adding a `#` sign (which is what seems to happen when you enter the hyperlink manually) is what caused the problem...

Comment: Hi, My next question is panding before 3 days. please check it from your end . Question is "one extra series is created in excel chart 2011"

Comment: If in this hyperlink ,how to create hyperlink without address of file path.because my hyperlink is not add a file path.

Comment: Hyperlink is not work in case when file is move another location.

Comment: In your script , hyperlink address is include the file path with sheet1 reference i.e. address is -> /private/var/root/Desktop/123.xls#Sheet1!A20. if my address is #Sheet1!A20 then hyperlink is to be work for any location.

Comment: if hyperlink address value is set to blank, then hyperlink is to be work properly for any location.                                    make new hyperlink of cell "A8" with properties {address:"", sub address:"$A$20", text to display:"Sheet1!A20"}